# Using jquery closest() and find() to return the actual HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have the following type of element below on my HTML webpage.

```
<div class="form-group>
    <div class="car">
        <div class="carIventory carDescription" contenteditable="true">This is car # 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tool">
        <button>Select me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are many of them depending on how many cars are displayed at a time.

When I click the button `Select me!` I use `closest()` and `find()` to get the nearest `<div>` with a class of `carDescription`.

Writing it out the console with this code:

```
var $element = $(e.target).closest('.form-group').find('.carDescription');
console.log("carDescription ", $element);
```

produces this:

```
jQuery.fn.init [div.carIventory.carDescription, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

But if I use this code instead:

```
const $element = document.querySelector('.carDescription');
console.log("carDescription ", $element);
```

I get the format I want:

```
<div class="carIventory carDescription" contenteditable="true">This is car # 1</div>
```

Is there a way to use `closest()` and `find()` to return the actual HTML element like `querySelector()` does?

Thanks!

Comment: You can see in jQuery that the first item in the array is your DOM element so you could just use `$element[0]`

Comment: In your jquery code, `$element` is the jquery representation of that element, hence you get a jquery.nf.init out.  You can either use jquery, eg `console.log("carDescription ", $element.text());` or you can convert it to a DOM node using `$element[0]`, something like `console.log("carDescription ", $element[0].innerHTML);` - personally I'd stick with jquery (hence the "something like")

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks!  `text()` does show me the contents of the `<div>` like this: `This is car # 1`.  But it doesn't show me the actual HTML elements like the format I need above.

Comment: Why use jQuery if you want the DOM?

Comment: Then `$lement[0].outerHTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the console showing you the DOM element. Depending on the browser's debugger they output different things. In your case you are seeing a jQuery object and not a reference to the DOM.

If you want the DOM you use [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) or `[0]` to reference the DOM element from jQuery's array like object.

```
var $element = $(e.target).closest('.form-group').find('.carDescription');
console.log("carDescription ", $element.get(0));
console.log("carDescription ", $element[0]);
```

Or just use modern DOM methods and skip jQuery all together.

```
var element = document.querySelector(e.target).closest(".form-group").querySelector('.carDescription');
console.log(element);
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option really worked.  I didn't know you could combine `querySelector()` and `closest()` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var $element = $(e.target).closest('.form-group').find('.carDescription');
console.log("carDescription ", $element.parent().html());
```

It will give the HTML output.

Comment: This is not the same as querySelector..... A string is not a DOM element....